# Sending quiz answers using a php form

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I have forms which work fine. I have a quiz which works fine.

When I incorporate the two they don't work fine :(

The quiz works as a quiz but it wont send it out using php to my email address.

Here is a bit of my code:

```
    <head>
      <script>
        CorrectAnswers = new Array();
        CorrectAnswers[0]=1;
        CorrectAnswers[1]=1;
        CorrectAnswers[2]=1;
        CorrectAnswers[3]=2;

        macrightchar='YES';
        macwrongchar='NO';
        winrightchar='YES';
        winwrongchar='NO';

        var platform = 'win'
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Mac') != -1) {platform = 'mac'}
        if (platform == 'mac') {
            rightchar = unescape(macrightchar)
            wrongchar = unescape(macwrongchar)
        }
        else {
            rightchar = unescape(winrightchar)
            wrongchar = unescape(winwrongchar)
        }

        function CheckAnswer(){
            var i = 0;
            var TotalCorrect = 0;
            var x = 0;
            var Score = 0;

            for (i=0; i<CorrectAnswers.length; i++){
                if (document.QuizForm.elements[i*2].selectedIndex == CorrectAnswers[i]){
                    document.QuizForm.elements[(i*2)+1].value = rightchar;
                    TotalCorrect++;
                }
                else{
                    document.QuizForm.elements[(i*2)+1].value = wrongchar;
                }
            }
                Score = Math.floor((TotalCorrect*100)/CorrectAnswers.length);
                document.CheckForm.ScoreBox.value = Score + '%';
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form name="QuizForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="forms/quiz/_process.php" onSubmit="return validate.check(this)">
        <table class="widthOneHundredPercent">

        <tr>
        <td class="tableCellFloat columnOne" valign="top">
        <label for="Big_Media_offers_a_great_multiplatform_tool">Big Media offers a great multiplatform tool</label>
        </td>
        <td class="tableCellFloat columnTwo" valign="top">
        <select name="0">
        <option>???</option>
        <option>True</option>
        <option>False</option>
        </select>
        <td valign=top>
        <input type="text" name="1" size=2 maxlength=2>
        </td>
        </td>
        </tr>

    <tr>
    <FORM name="CheckForm">
        <td align="center">
        <font face="Geneva,Arial"><input type="button" VALUE="Check" onClick="CheckAnswer()"> Your score is  <input type=text name="ScoreBox" size="4" maxlength="4"></font>
        <center><input type="submit" value="Submit Form" /></center>
        </form>
```

When submit is pressed it will change the end of my file name in the address bar from quiz.php to quiz.php?ScoreBox=75%25. So it takes my correct answers and wrong answers.

I need the quiz to show a live right and wrong answers when check scores is clicked but I also need to send the results using PHP.

If I'm going at it completely wrong perhaps someone can point me in the right direction to start fresh.

Regards.

Comment: Can your PHP build send emails at all?

Comment: yes, it is a paid system so I'd rather not add the code here.

Comment: you have a php problem (sending the emails, not using forms or showing results) but all we can see here is javascript and html

Comment: We're going to struggle to help without seeing quiz.php =/

Comment: Hi @mishu, the reason I did not add the php code is that I am paying for it so I cannot share it, I assume it will be OK to share certain snippets of it. Perhaps my best bet would be to create a development website and upload the quiz there so people can view the source and help? Would that be better?

Comment: View source won't let us see the PHP script.

Comment: What is the best way of me going about this then? I need help but this is a paid service so I cannot just freely give it out, can anyone suggest something which can allow me to get help with this code?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou there are several possible problems, so it would be hard to guess; the first questions I can think of: did you try to create a script that just sends an email on that server, to isolate the problem? are you using the mail function or another system? are you sure that the email is not sent or it isn't received?

Comment: @mishu I had a quiz, which uses a button to check the scores, as you can see. I also have a normal working form, which I have subscribed to a form builder to use and pay for. I have taken the form builder code (which definitely works when used without a quiz as I use it on many of my websites) and put the quiz inside the form builder code. The form, I believe, does not send, because if it did it would take me through to a thank you page as thats what my form builder code does. Also it's changing the url in the address bar which seems to be a clash with the javascript code in the head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things I notice here:

- `QuizForm` doesn't have a submit button and does not appear to be submitted dynamically (may just not be shown). Perhaps this form and `CheckForm` can be combined.
- `CheckForm` doesn't have a `method` defined, which is why the submit puts a query string on it
- The score is being submitted instead of the raw answers. Perhaps this is desired behavior, but it leaves the ability for someone to just submit they got a great score.

The answer could be as simple as moving the submit button from `CheckForm` to `QuizForm`.

Comment: Fantastic spot. This is what I was looking for. It was indeed that, or very similar. I changed it and it did not work, but then I asked myself why I had two forms, one containing the submit buttons and one the quiz. I made it all one form and it now works, but I figured that out because you pointed out the change in form names. Thank you very much :) I understand my quiz is not the best and may be changing it now anyway but as long as it works I can proceed to make it more complex. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a closing `<form>` tag for 'QuizForm' before you open 'CheckForm'.

[edit]Actually, QuizForm doesn't seem to have a submission method.

Comment: Hi grim, yes good spot, I do already have one but as I only copied a snippet of the quiz and not the wholee quiz I stupidly forgot to add the bottom bit. I can assure you I have closed the table and the form.  :( Thanks.